# Проблемы с ajax и php

Tags: ajax

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<?php 
require "config.php";
// You can access the values posted by jQuery.ajax
// through the global variable $_POST, like this:

?>
</head>
<body>


 <form id="foo" action="" method="POST">
    <input id="test" name="bar" type="text"  />

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
<?php 
$a = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `test`");
while($b = mysqli_fetch_assoc($a)){
    echo $b['name']."<br>";
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#foo").submit(function() { //устанавливаем событие отправки для формы с id=form
         var foo = $(this).serialize();  //собераем все данные из формы
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //Метод отправки
            url: "send.php", //путь до php фаила отправителя
            data: foo,
            success: function() {
                   //код в этом блоке выполняется при успешной отправке сообщения
                   alert("Ваше сообщение отпрвлено!");
       
};
       
            });
   });
});    
</script>
<?php
echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

```html
<?php 
require "config.php";
// You can access the values posted by jQuery.ajax
// through the global variable $_POST, like this:
if(isset($_POST['bar'])) {
 $bar = $_POST['bar'];
 

mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `test` (`name`) VALUES ('".$bar."')");


}
$a = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `test`");
while($b = mysqli_fetch_assoc($a)){
    echo $b['name']."<br>";
}
?>
```

почему данные не отправляются на  send.php что не так с кодом,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь инструментами разработчика в Google Chrome / вкладка Network (нажмите F12), чтобы увидеть куда отправляется ajax запрос.

А если по сути, то в "url" нужно прописывать не название php файла, а путь к файлу на сервере, например http://127.0.0.1/send.php